# ¿Existe Algo como el metodo ToString de java en c++?

Tags: c++

¿y si lo hay como se implementa?

En java por ejemplo, es posible crear en una clase el metodo to string

```
public String toString (){
    String mensaje="Este es mi mensaje" 
    return mensaje;
}
```

para luego al ser llamado

```
imprimir(clase)

salida: Este es mi mensaje
```

Es decir sin necesidad de llamar a ningun metodo de la clase.

Entonces.
¿Existe Algo como el metodo ToString de java en c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En C++ existen los operadores de conversión:

```
class MiClase
{
public:
  explicit operator std::string()
  {
    return "Este es mi mensaje";
  }
};

void imprimir(std::string const& mensaje)
{
  std::cout << mensaje;
}

int main()
{
  MiClase miclase;
  imprimir(static_cast<std::string>(miclase));
}
```

Conviene usar `explicit` para evitar que algunas conversiones se realizen *sin querer*. Al usar `explicit` se fuerza a que las conversiones deban ser explícitas (por ejemplo usando `static_cast`)

Answer (score -1):

Sacado de esta respuesta en StackOverflow en ingles de la pregunta: [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c)

La forma mas facil de convertir un int a string en C++.

C++ 11 introduce std::to_string, que serian las contra partes de C atoi e itoa pero expresadas en términos de std::string.

```
#include <string> 

std::string s = std::to_string(variable_int);
```

Podrias evitar nombrar el tipo de variable usando la palabra clave `auto`

```
auto s = std::to_string(variable_int);
```

Comment: Aunque la respuesta esta bien, no es lo que esta preguntando.. en Java (o en C#) las clases que heredan de object tienen un metodo que se puede sobrescribir que se llama ToString. y que imprime o un valor por defecto, o lo que se pida al usar la clase como string (por ejemplo al hacer una salida a consola de clase)